# Метафорой чего может быть перепёлка?

Tags: значение-слов, литература, метафора

> Трудно передать словами, какою **перепелкой** влетел в комнату молодой прогрессист.
>
> *И. С. Тургенев. «Отцы и дети».*

Что имеет в виду автор?

Какие такие характерные черты есть у перепёлки, чтоб поведение человека можно было сравнить с перепёлкой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Источник изображения: Автор: Luis Miguel Bugallo Sánchez (Lmbuga Commons)(Lmbuga Galipedia)Publicada por/Publish by: Luis Miguel Bugallo Sánchez - собственная работа, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=353465

---

> Перепела держатся на земле, в густой траве и на полях, более или менее
> общественны. Прекрасно бегают, летают быстро, но редко продолжительно.
> Кричат пронзительно, но монотонно. Питаются мелкими семенами и
> насекомыми.
>
> [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0)]

Что из этого может послужить основой для метафоры?

Например:

- «[Перепела] летают быстро»: *«перепелкой влетел»* — быстро влетел?
- «[Перепела] Кричат пронзительно, но монотонно»: *«перепелкой влетел»* — влетел, крича/говоря громко пронзительно и монотонно?

---

Возможно, имеется в виду не птица, а танец?

> **Перепёлка** — украинский и белорусский весенний народный танец-игра. **Танец исполняется в круге, в центре которого находится участница («перепёлка»). Во время пения «перепёлка» в такт словам песни показывает: то у неё болит головка, то белые рученьки, то ножки и т.д.** Во второй части игры идёт старик и нагайку несёт, или милый-чернобровый несёт рубашечку (вариант: новые чоботы). Во всех вариантах игры во второй части «перепёлочка» разрывает круг. Затем игра начинается снова. Украинский танец исполняется в быстром темпе, белорусский — в умеренном.
>
> *[[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86))]*

Поведение «перепёлки» в танце тоже трудно сравнить с поведением героя в книге.

---

Может, есть какое-то характерное поведение перепёлки, сравнение с которым легло в основу метафоры в книге, и в основу танца?

Comment: Хороший вопрос! Надеюсь, что будут интересные ответы.

Comment: А почему "какою перепелк**ой**", а не "как**ою** перепёлк**ою**"? По стилистике желательна одинаковая форма, а может быть, и необходима. Могу предположить, что разная форма — разговорный вариант.

Comment: @oleedd Мне тоже это место показалось неправильным. Но если подумать, то придраться вроде бы не к чему — и там и там родительный падеж.

Comment: А форма творительного падежа же разная. Вот бы правило найти. У Розенталя нашёл только про архаичность окончания *-ою*.

Comment: @oleedd Мне правило найти не удалось. Исходя из того, что Розенталь пишет про архаичность ***-ою***, я думаю, что ***-ою*** постепенно стало переходить в ***-ой*** путём утраты конечного гласного звука [у]. Окончание ***-ою*** звучит [ойу]; перестали произносить звук [у] на конце, и получилось ***-ой***. Возможно, во времена Тургенева одни слова всё ещё произносили с [у] на конце, а в других перестали произносить [у] — потому в предложении одно слово с [у], а другое нет. Сейчас равноправными считаются оба варианта, и нам кажется неправильным разное написание в одном словосочетании.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе часто окончания совпадают, но иногда разные. Даже попалось такое: *была такою красивою и таинственной*.

Comment: @oleedd Ну так, может, это потому, что перестали у части слов произносить [у] на конце, а у другой чаcти по традиции произносили?

Comment: Может. Да и сейчас так же. Но тогда какая логика у этой традиции? "Перепёлкою" что-то не очень звучит, как и "таинственною". Можно предположить, что в длинных словах *-ою* не звучит.

Comment: @oleedd Хорошая мысль. Часто изменения в звуках слов происходят из-за желания упросить произношение. «Какою» — короткое слово и [у] на конце сохранилось, а «перепелкой» — длинное слово и [у] утратилось. _«Красивою и таинственной»_ — может быть та же логика.

Comment: Да, интересное объяснение, логичное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У перепёлок в обычае, довольно близко подпустив человека, неожиданно взлетать из высокой травы или колосьев, — так что можно даже испугаться. Тургенев был охотником и повадки разных птиц хорошо знал. Кроме того, считается, что птицы в основном глупы. Смысл фразы: молодой прогрессист влетел (т. е. на самом деле он, конечно, вбежал) в комнату так стремительно, что мог даже испугать, — и поступил он так не от большого ума.

Answer (score 2):

**Характер перепелов**  можно определить так: с одной стороны, это **пугливые** птицы, а с другой – шумные, неадекватные и неудобные для содержания в домашних условиях.  Они легко пугаются, приходят возбуждение – и тогда кричат, подпрыгивают, пытаются взлететь, ударяются об клетку, так что их поведение трудно предугадать.

**Именно такой характер был у Ситникова**, беспокойный и непредсказуемый. Сначала он  волновался, что его выставят из приличного общества, куда его не звали, «бормотал какую-то дрянь», даже сел на свою шляпу от волнения,  но потом осмелел и «затрещал на славу».

Ситников как назойливый шум, который отвлекает на себя внимание, и тогда ослабевает высокий настрой и упрощаются чувства.

***Влететь перепелкой*** – значит появиться неожиданно, создав много шума и беспокойства и прервав  беседу на полуслове.

**Отрывок из романа**

*Неожиданный случай вывел ее из затруднения: дворецкий доложил о приезде Ситникова. **Трудно передать словами, какою перепелкой влетел в комнату молодой прогрессист.** Решившись, с свойственною ему назойливостью, поехать в деревню к женщине, которую он едва знал, которая никогда его не приглашала, но у которой, по собранным сведениям, гостили такие умные и близкие ему люди, он все-таки **робел до мозга костей** и, вместо того чтобы произнести заранее затверженные извинения и приветствия, пробормотал какую-то дрянь ...запнулся и потерялся до того, что сел на собственную шляпу. Однако, так как никто его не прогнал и Анна Сергеевна даже представила его тетке и сестре, он скоро оправился и затрещал на славу.*

Comment: Большинство птиц — пугливые, шумные и неадекватные. Я и писал: считается — неспроста! — что птицы в основном глупы. Да и не только птицы :) У птиц есть интеллектуальная элита: хищные, вороновые, попугаи... но наверняка и там попадаются отдельные дурацкие экземпляры.

Comment: Егор, ваша перепелка не так уж глупа – взлетает (ВЫЛЕТАЕТ из укрытия), чтобы напугать охотника.  А у Тургенева  она, напротив,  ВЛЕТАЕТ куда-то.  А что это значит – влететь перепелкой или как перепелка?  Здесь и надо раскрыть значение  признакового обстоятельства, найти подходящий  синоним.

Comment: Sharon, у Тургенева она тоже вылетает ОТКУДА-ТО :) «А что это значит – влететь перепелкой или как перепелка?» — я ж писал, что это значит. Это значит: «влететь как человеческая особь с птичьими мозгами».

Comment: Разве это единственная особь с таким мозгами?  Добавьте еще что-нибудь узнаваемое. Чтобы можно было сказать: именно перепелкой, и никак иначе.

Comment: Нет, далеко не единственная :)

Comment: Да. я тоже это заметила :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я проголосовал за него, но принял всё-таки ответ Егора. Я думаю, что, вероятно, эта метафора возникла именно в результате столкновением с поведением перепёлок на природе, на охоте, в частности. Насчёт характера Ситникова, тут нужен глубокий анализ, чтоб понять можно его поведение в целом сравнить с поведением перепёлки или нет. В конкретной ситуации вбегания в комнату, я считаю, что Егор правильно раскрыл суть метафоры, хотя вы тоже высказали похожее суждение.